# What is the right way to solve this error Can't call method "fetchrow_array" on an undefined value

Tags: perl

Below is the perl code I'm using for a script to be run on crontab

```
if($enable_family_members==0)
{
  my $sql="select name from test where testid IN (". join(',',  @set) . ')';
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n"; 
}

while (my ($name)=$sth->fetchrow_array())
{
  print "name: $name";
}
```

When I try to run this script I get an error `Can't call method "fetchrow_array" on an undefined value at line 9`.   When I try to use `our` **keyword** instead of `my` **keyword** in $sth, I don't get error. What is the right way to solve this error.

Comment: My answer was regarding catching error on the `prepare` now removed, I missed the probably correct variable scoping answer.

Comment: You would not have this problem if you had used `use strict`. Also, you should not interpolate variables directly into your query string, you should use placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$sth` variable is visible only inside `if` block. Try:

```
if($enable_family_members==0) {
    my $sql="select name from test where testid IN (". join(',',  @set) . ')';
    my  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n"; 
    while (my ($name)=$sth->fetchrow_array()) {
        print "name: $name";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make it visible outside if block. If I use elsif after I'm going to use the same while to retrieve the values.

Comment: declare it outside `my sth; if(...) {...; $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);} `

Comment: @user2770039, you can read more about variable scoping here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Variable-scoping and here http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=66677